# How does the Devil Fruit user know how to activate their power?

Tags: one-piece

For some Paramecia type, to use their power, they must do something with parts of their body.

Just like how Bartholomew must cross his finger to create a barrier, or Foxy must stick his thumb, middle, and ring finger together to create Noro Noro beam.

But how can they know that crossing or sticking three of their fingers will activate their powers?

Comment: Now your question makes me curious - **How come Law came to know about his power - we have seen him struggling when he ate the devil fruit**

Comment: I think they are just there to show that now they gonna use their power like shouting the name of technique and to activate they learn and practice and master themselves.

Comment: @exexzian well, yeah, thats also the reason I'm asking about this question by the way.

Comment: @mirroroftruth yeah, if the power is just like Luffy or Buggy I think I can understand, but for other Paramecia that must have some condition to active their power, that is what I'm not understand here. Like I said, Bartholomew or Foxy, I never seen their power active without crossing or sticking three of their fingers right?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but crossing finger, hand are just to show and to know about power they will be aware as soon as they eat the devil fruit but need time and training to use it properly

Comment: Maybe the same way Spiderman learned. He just accidentally put his fingers that way and super natural stuff happend.

Comment: @exexzian the devil fruit user will know as soon as he eats the fruit

Comment: @mirroroftruth I doubt on that.. We have seen law trying random things to use his power - moreover he wasn't even sure of what does his devil fruit does in actual

Comment: @mirroroftruth however I do consider your earlier comment to be reliable `they learn and practice and master themselves`

Comment: @exexzian that might be right, know that they power but don't know what they are.

Comment: @SirDuckduck lol, that's also what i'm thinking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seem to be 3 different ways to learn this:

- Experimentation

If a user has no idea exactly how his fruit can be used, he can play around with different motions movements or just live his life.  Brook never figured out what his fruit could do until he was already dead.  Hypothetically, Bartolomeo could have lived his life without finding out if he hadn't happened to cross his fingers the right way (assuming that is required).

- Reason

Some users have some idea what their fruit is when they eat it. Others only have partial knowledge of their abilities. The Barrier Fruit is based off a [children's game](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11477/how-does-the-barrier-taunt-work?s=2%7C1.2216). If Bartolomeo knew that he had this fruit, they could have tried to enact that game to see if it worked.  This can be combined with experimentation to improve fruits.  Bartholomew Kuma and Law seem to have decided to try appying their abilities to abstract concepts and studied their ability to learn how to do this.  Other fruits may have simular unusual uses that are never noticed as the users aren't as smart as those two.

- Historical Research

Devil Fruits are not single use.  They are reincarnated into a new fruit to be eaten when the user dies.  This means, for instance, that Law knew exactly what fruit he had before he knew how to use it. There are records and second/third hand sources stating what some fruits can do. That is exactly why he knows that you can make someone immortal with it despite having never done so.  For our repeated example, Bartolomeo might know he has to cross his fingers because he could have read that it was required.  This means, of course, that someone else must have learned it by on of the first two methods and there may be other unknown uses.

- Final Note

Devil Fruits do not change during the person's life (with Brook as the possible exception).  A Logia fruit does not itself get stronger as the user does but the user can get more creative, more practiced, and more experienced in combat in general. This means that training can't make the fruit itself more powerful or generate new powers that previously were impossible (only undiscovered).

Comment: I think the Historical Research and Experimentation are make sense for me, and the Reason point I think it's only for few Fruit, but of course `This can be combined with experimentation to improve fruits.` Thanks for explanation @kaine nice one!

Comment: @JTR actually it works for most. Luffy invented his Gears, Brook: water running and others, Robin: giganto stuff, and (best of all) chopper learned how to make 4 more forms tha other zoan and a drug which facilitates that. These are all creative uses.  It doesnt work if they dont know the power somewhat first.

Comment: for improving their power maybe true, but I mean when they really have no idea how to use the power at the first time they ate it. Not all Paramecia (mostly) know how to active their power even they know what kind of fruit that they eat right? they must research and make an experiment just like you said. Luffy already know he's a rubber man when he's kid, later he improve his power.

Answer (score 1):

I think devil fruit users has no specific way of activating their power rather than **training** and **practice**. They discover it by their own because as we can see on each devil fruit users learns new techniques after they train hard using their ability.

We don't exactly know the story of other fruit users how they discovered to activate their powers but we can make Luffy as an example because from the start we have seen his story.

After Luffy became a rubber man when he was still a kid he doesn't know how to activate his ability. But through his every day training and challenge to defeat his brother Ace he created and discovered his very first technique *Gomu Gomu no Pistol*. And created more techniques as he discover more ways to use his ability. Another example is his Second Gear before he needs to sit to activate it but later after training and practice even standing he can activate it.

As for Bartholomew and Foxy since we haven't seen their story we can assume that they also discovered it through the same process or accidentally discovered it. They did a lot of tests to discover a more effective way to use their power. For example Foxy might discovered that when he stick his thumb, middle, and ring finger together his *Noro Noro Beam* last longer than using only one of his finger. The same as Bartholomew, he might discovered it through practice that crossing his finger creates a stronger barrier than just one finger.

Another good example is Flamingo. He only discovered and learned his awaken through training and practice.

So activating their power depends on what they discover from themselves of what they are capable to do and refine it throug training and practice.

Comment: Activating the ability of Devil Fruit that I mean is like Bartolomew and Foxy, not like Luffy, when  he's still a kid, he already know that he's a rubber man and later he can improver his power. But Bartolomew and foxy when first time eat the fruits, I think they have no idea what the power they have.

Comment: By the way, for if true that Foxy are "accidentally" sticking three of his finger, I think he's really stupid. lol. Well, maybe that's true and make sense for Bartolomew when he crossing finger then the Barrier is activate

Comment: @JTR we can't assume that Bartolomew and Foxy doesn't know about their fruit because its not shown in manga. They might or might not be.

Comment: @JTR about Foxy we'll we never know how he discover how to use his power its just a speculation that he accidentally discover how to use it and after all he is stupid anyway. lol.. but I like the guys answer above its better..

Comment: yeah I know, but maybe Foxy is best example to what [SirDuckDuck](http://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1526/sirduckduck) comment in my question about how spiderman learned his power lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you eat a Devil Fruit and don't know what the power is, you can discover it by accident or when you're in danger. But there is one thing you will know you ate a Devil Fruit: because they taste horrible.